# How can I populate my listbox with only certain columns from a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a listbox that I populated using this code:

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim LRow As Long
Dim Myarray As Variant

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Mark1.LEADLISTDROPDOWN.Value)
 
 With ws
 LRow = .Range("BJ" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 
 Set Rng = ws.Range("A2:KH" & LRow)
 
PopoutLeadListBox.RowSource = Rng.Address(External:=True)
 
 End With
 
End Sub
```

However, I want to adjust it to where only certain columns are loaded, notably columns (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 52, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 124, 145, 221, 234, 247, 294)

Can I adjust my existing code to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```vb
Private Sub Userform_initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim arrCol, i, j, arrList
    arrCol = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 52, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 124, 145, 221, 234, 247, 294)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Mark1.LEADLISTDROPDOWN.Value)
    With ws
        ' Get the last row
        LRow = .Range("BJ" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' redim an array to store the drop down list
        ReDim arrList(1 To LRow, UBound(arrCol))
        For i = 1 To LRow
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrCol)
                arrList(i, j) = ws.Cells(i, arrCol(j)).Value
            Next
        Next
        With Me.PopoutLeadListBox
            ' set how many columns 
            .ColumnCount = UBound(arrCol) + 1
            ' set width for every column
            .ColumnWidths = Mid(Application.Rept(";25", UBound(arrCol) + 1), 2)
            ' load data
            .List = arrList
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One method worth looking into is the Advanced Filter.

**Pros:**

- Incredibly fast when working with large data sets
- Choose only the columns you want returned
- Rearrange the columns as needed
- Filter the data, if required

**Cons:**

- Requires an additional output worksheet
- Must reference column names (not numbers) of the data set

**(1)** First, insert a new worksheet and rename it "**AdvFilter**".

**(2)** Next, in row 5 of the "AdvFilter" worksheet (starting in cell A5), list all of the columns from your data set that you want to be returned, in the order you wish them to appear. If you need to filter the data set by one or more columns, input the column names in row 1 (starting in cell A1), with the corresponding filter criteria in row 2 (see Figure 2 below).

**Figure 1:** Sample Data Set

[image: sample_data.jpg]

**Figure 2:** Advanced Filter Setup

[image: advanced_filter.jpg]

**(3)** Lastly, use the following code in the UserForm_Initialize procedure:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim rgSource As Range
    Dim rgOutput As Range
    Dim rgCriteria As Range
    Dim rgResults As Range
    Dim lRows As Long
    
'Clear the previous search results
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("AdvFilter")
    Set rgOutput = wsOutput.Range("A5")
    rgOutput.CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents

'Output the new search results
    Set wsSource = Sheets(Mark1.LEADLISTDROPDOWN.Value)
    Set rgSource = wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rgCriteria = wsOutput.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    On Error Resume Next
    rgSource.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCriteria, rgOutput.CurrentRegion
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error Code: " & Err.Number
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Populate the ListBox with the filter results
    Set rgResults = rgOutput.CurrentRegion
    lRows = rgResults.Rows.Count - 1
    If lRows > 0 Then
        Me.PopoutLeadListBox.RowSource = rgResults.Offset(1).Resize(lRows).Address(External:=True)
    Else
        MsgBox "No records found"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Figure 3:** Advanced Filter Results

[image: filter_results.jpg]